# MSB307 Getting error on build Could not copy "C:\Users\....\.nuget" to bin

Tags: build-error

I have added a new reference leadtools.Raster.common from nuget in my Azure function solution .
The solution version is .Net Core 3.1 and function app version is V3.
I am trying to build the solution but I am getting an error like below .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiEjm.png)

I have tried creating a new project with same version I am able to build and deploy but the current project on which I am working is throwing the above error with 10 retry failed .
Please note my current project is in Dev ops and connected to a repository.

I tried creating new project with same version it worked I believe some folder level restriction are causing this issue . I have copied the folder in another folder and tried to build it worked but the source folder still throwing same error.